# .click() on button failing to process(no errors)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to create an options page for my very first extension. I am brand new to coding, so I'm sure that I've made a simple faux-pas. Unfortunately, I'm having issues with some basic functionality that I've had working in my base extension for some time and without issue. I've reviewed the syntax and searched everywhere I can think of for why this doesn't work AND doesn't provide an error as to why it fails. I have reproduced the behavior in 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/technicallynick/1c8znbh6/). Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

--HTML--

```
<title>Options for My Extension</title>

<script src="jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>Toggle Menu to "Default = Out"?</h1>
<select id="Menu_Hide">
<option value="No">No</option>
<option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
<br />
<button id="Save">Save</button>
<br />
<button id="Reset">Reset</button>
</body>
```

--JS--

```
function save_data(){
    var ob = document.getElementById("Menu_Hide");
    var txt = ob.children[ob.selectIndex].value;
    localStorage["Menu_Hide"] = txt;
}

function load_data(){
    console.log("This loads just fine!")
    var data = localStorage["Menu_Hide"];
    if (!data){
        return;
    }
var select = document.getElementById("Menu_Hide");
var found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < select.children.length && !found; i++){
    var child = select.children[i];
    if (child.value == data) {
        child.selected = "true";
        found = true;
    }
}    
}

window.onLoad = load_data();

$('#Save').click(function() {
    alert('Settings Saved!');
    save_data();
})
```

--manifest.json-- (update)

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My first attempt at being useful.",
  "description": "This extension will add additional functionality to some pages.",
  "version": "1.5",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["start.js"],
    "matches": 
      [
        "https://<url1>"
        "https://<url2>",

      ]
  }],
 "web_accessible_resources": ["run.js"],
  "permissions": [ 
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
]
}
```

Comment: Typo: it's [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) not `selectIndex`. Also the fiddle does give errors, first one being jQuery not being defined as you didn't include it correctly for the fiddle, and then an error `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined` for the line where you were using the wrong property name

Comment: `window.onLoad = load_data();` should be `window.onLoad = load_data;`. You are invoking the function immediately instead of assigning a reference to the function

Comment: Ok, so after fixing the fiddle with the above recommendations, it does in fact work on fiddle. However, in loading this exact same code in a Chrome extension fails as an "options_page".  Anyone have any insight as to why this would fail? There is nothing logged to console. Nothing I can see as to why the "save_data" function doesn't fire when the "save" button is clicked.

Comment: A little more information about the extension that I thought about this morning that is probably relevant is that it's a 'content-script' extension, rather than a 'background' extension. I've updated the post with the json data for the extension.

Comment: If you're working on a Chrome extension please add that tag to your question

Comment: In your fiddle the click works fine on the button, so what is the pbl?

Comment: Tag added. Thanks for pointing that out!
The issue is that while this works correctly in the fiddle, the exact same code fails in an options page for my extension. I believe this may be some restriction with "content-script" extensions, but I can't find any documentation stating as much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any supporting documentation, but I have found that the ".click()" functionality does NOT work for an "options" page in an extension. However, rather than using a separate page altogether, you can use a browser action "default_popup" and click functionality (as well as other event listeners) work here.

I hope this helps someone in the future!